# Equivalent of bytea type in Cassandra

Tags: types, cassandra, binary

I don't know what is the equivalent of the `bytea` type of Postgres in Cassandra.
For exemple, I have in my table in Postgres a field which contains :
`\x3500000000000050a0` 
And i want to put exactly the same value in Cassandra.
I try to use the `blob` type, but it didn't work.

Thanks for help

Comment: but it didn't work ??  What is the error ?

Comment: This page might help you.  http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html

Comment: What language/driver you using? Theres always `textAsBlob` or `bigintAsBlob` etc if you actually want to pass it as a string, but many drivers provide a way to just push your byte array without converting it to a string via prepared statements.